# How to get parent property name in api model validation process asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, model-validation

I have a class model as below:

```
public class QuataShareSurplussFormModel
{

    public QuataShareSurplussOfferLetterModel offeredLetters { get; set; }
    [ListValidations]
    [ListDuplicateValidations]
    public List<QuataShareClassModel> quataShareClass { get; set; }
    [ListValidations]
    [ListDuplicateValidations]
    public List<SurplusClassModel> surplusClass { get; set; }
    [ListDuplicateValidations]
    public List<OfferedLettersClauseModel> lettersClauses { get; set; }
    [ListDuplicateValidations]
    public List<OfferedLettersExclusionsModel> lettersExclusions { get; set; }
    [ListDuplicateValidations]
    public List<OfferedLettersGeneralConditionsModel> lettersGeneralConditions { get; set; }
    [ListDuplicateValidations]
    public List<OfferedLettersSpecialConditionsModel> lettersSpecialConditions { get; set; }
    [ListDuplicateValidations]
    public List<OfferedLettersGeneralExclusionsModel> lettersGeneralExclusions { get; set; }

}
```

`quataShareClass` property has the following items:

```
public class QuataShareClassModel
{
    public int offeredLetterId { get; set; }
    [PropRequiredValidation]
    [PropRangeValidation(1, int.MaxValue)]
    public int? classId { get; set; }
    [PropRequiredValidation]
    [PropRangeValidation(0, long.MaxValue)]
    public long? maxLimitOfCover { get; set; }
    [PropRequiredValidation]
    [PropRangeValidation(0, byte.MaxValue)]
    public byte? baseDataServiceCurrencyTypeId { get; set; }
    [PropRequiredValidation]
    [PropRangeValidation(0, int.MaxValue)]
    public Nullable<int> exchangeRate { get; set; }
    [PropRequiredValidation]
    [PropRangeValidation(0, long.MaxValue)]
    [CalculativeIRRCheck(nameof(maxLimitOfCover), nameof(exchangeRate))]
    public long? maxLimitOfCoverInIRR { get; set; }
    [PropRequiredValidation]
    [PropRangeValidation(0, byte.MaxValue)]
    public long? commission { get; set; }
    [PropRequiredValidation]
    [PropRangeValidation(1, int.MaxValue)]
    public int? lastLossRatio { get; set; }
}
```

For example, say i want to validate `commission` property

```
public class PropRangeValidation : RangeAttribute
{
    private readonly double _Minimum;
    private readonly double _Maximum;

    public PropRangeValidation(double minimum, double maximum) : base( minimum, maximum)
    {
        this._Minimum = minimum;
        this._Maximum = maximum;
    }
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var valueStr = value?.ToString();
        var valueDbl = Convert.ToDouble(valueStr);

        if ((valueDbl < _Minimum || valueDbl > _Maximum) && valueStr!=null)
        {
            var memberName = validationContext.MemberName;
            var errorMsg = string.Format(Resources.RangeViolation, valueDbl, memberName);
            var errorCode = ValidationError.Required.ToString();
            var error = string.Format("{0}|{1}|{2}", errorMsg, errorCode, memberName);
            return new ValidationResult(error);
        }
        return null;


    }
}
```

How to get `commission` parent property name from `ValidationContext` ? i mean

```
public List<QuataShareClassModel> quataShareClass { get; set; }
```

I need to get `quataShareClass` name.

Something like this:

```
var parentProp=ValidationContext.ParentProperty //results to `quataShareClass`
```

Comment: Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you implement `IValidatableObject` interface. It determines whether the specified object is valid or not. There is a `Validate` method that returns a collection of `ValidationResult` so you can use `yield return` to get the results. You do not need to call the `Validate` method, it manages by .net.

```
public class QuataShareClassModel : IValidatableObject
{
    public int offeredLetterId { get; set; }
    [PropRequiredValidation]
    [PropRangeValidation(1, int.MaxValue)]
    public int? classId { get; set; }
    [PropRequiredValidation]
    [PropRangeValidation(0, long.MaxValue)]
    public long? maxLimitOfCover { get; set; }
    [PropRequiredValidation]
    [PropRangeValidation(0, byte.MaxValue)]
    public byte? baseDataServiceCurrencyTypeId { get; set; }
    [PropRequiredValidation]
    [PropRangeValidation(0, int.MaxValue)]
    public Nullable<int> exchangeRate { get; set; }
    [PropRequiredValidation]
    [PropRangeValidation(0, long.MaxValue)]
    [CalculativeIRRCheck(nameof(maxLimitOfCover), nameof(exchangeRate))]
    public long? maxLimitOfCoverInIRR { get; set; }
    [PropRequiredValidation]
    [PropRangeValidation(0, byte.MaxValue)]
    public long? commission { get; set; }
    [PropRequiredValidation]
    [PropRangeValidation(1, int.MaxValue)]
    public int? lastLossRatio { get; set; }

    public QuataShareSurplussFormModel QuataShareSurplussFormModel { get; set; }
    
    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (condition)
            yield return new ValidationResult("your message...", new[]
            {
                nameof([YourProperName])
            });

        if (condition)
            yield return new ValidationResult("your massage...", new[]
            {
                nameof(YourProperName1), nameof(YourProperName2)
            });
    }
}
```

Take a look at [IValidatableObject Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject.validate?view=net-5.0)

**UPDATE:**

Add *inverse navigation property* to access `QuataShareSurplussFormModel`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mohammad , but please elaborate on the details,How object validation is going to be helping finding parent property name in main class?

Comment: @Abolfazl you can implement `IValidatableObject` in the **superclass** instead of **derived class**, by this you can validate `commission` property and also access to the *parent property name*.

Comment: @Abolfazl In your **derived class** there is no **inverse navigation property** to access the **superclass**. So you can add inverse navigation property to access the *parent property name*.